# "how to fix 'UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other'"

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

Whenever I try to install opencv I found this "Solving environment: failed" and then "UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other"

```
Package pytest conflicts for:
anaconda==2019.03=py37_0 -> pytest-doctestplus==0.3.0=py37_0 -> pytest[version='>=2.8']
Package importlib_metadata conflicts for:
pytest-arraydiff -> pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-remotedata -> pytest[version='>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
importlib_metadata
pytest-doctestplus -> pytest[version='>=2.8'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
astropy -> pytest-astropy -> pytest-doctestplus[version='>=0.1.2,>=0.1.3,>=0.2.0'] -> pytest[version='>=2.8'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
path.py -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.5']
pytest-openfiles -> pytest[version='>=2.8.0,>=3.1'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest-astropy -> pytest-doctestplus[version='>=0.1.2,>=0.1.3,>=0.2.0'] -> pytest[version='>=2.8'] -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
pytest -> importlib_metadata[version='>=0.12']
Package hdf5 conflicts for:
hdf5
pytables -> hdf5[version='1.10.1,1.8.17|1.8.17.*,1.8.18|1.8.18.*']
h5py -> hdf5[version='1.8.17|1.8.17.*,1.8.18|1.8.18.*,>=1.10.1,<1.10.2.0a0,>=1.10.2,<1.10.3.0a0']
Package mkl-service conflicts for:
mkl-service
```