# UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Tags: anaconda, conda

I am running on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have run into issues with Anaconda.
Due to package inconsistencies, I can no longer install, update or remove packages.

```
$ conda info
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found

     active environment : None 
            shell level : 0
       user config file : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
 populated config files : /home/ubuntu/.condarc
          conda version : 4.7.5
    conda-build version : 3.2.2
         python version : 2.7.15.final.0
       virtual packages : 
       base environment : /home/ubuntu/anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/linux-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /home/ubuntu/anaconda/pkgs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /home/ubuntu/anaconda/envs
                          /home/ubuntu/.conda/envs
               platform : linux-64
             user-agent : conda/4.7.5 requests/2.21.0 CPython/2.7.15 Linux/4.4.0-161-generic ubuntu/16.04.6 glibc/2.23
                UID:GID : 1000:1000
             netrc file : None 
           offline mode : False
```

I tried all the suggestions in this issue, but nothing is working:

[The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55527354/the-environment-is-inconsistent-please-check-the-package-plan-carefully)

Also

["how to fix 'UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57150825/how-to-fix-unsatisfiableerror-the-following-specifications-were-found-to-be-i)
E.g. -

```
$ conda activate base 
$ conda update conda-build
$ conda update conda-build
$conda update --all
$ conda install anaconda
$ conda install -c anaconda anaconda
$ conda install gxx_impl_linux-64
```

Here's the full output:

```
buntu@ip-10-0-1-71:~/clamav-devel$ conda list gxx_impl_linux-64   
# packages in environment at /home/ubuntu/anaconda:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel 
gxx_impl_linux-64         7.3.0                hdf63c60_1
ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-71:~/clamav-devel$ conda install gxx_impl_linux-64
WARNING conda.base.context:use_only_tar_bz2(632): Conda is constrained to only using the old .tar.bz2 file format because you have conda-build installed, and it is <3.18.3.  Update or remove conda-build t
o get smaller downloads and faster extractions.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices founddone
Solving environment: /
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:                         -
  - conda-forge/linux-64::zstd==1.4.0=h3b9ef0a_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::binstar==0.11.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sphinx_rtd_theme==0.1.9=py27_0
  - featuretools/linux-64::featuretools==0.3.0=np111py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::xlsxwriter==0.8.4=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gxx_impl_linux-64==7.3.0=hdf63c60_1
  - defaults/linux-64::cffi==1.11.5=py27he75722e_1
  - defaults/linux-64::curl==7.62.0=hbc83047_0
  - defaults/linux-64::h5py==2.8.0=py27h989c5e5_3
  - defaults/linux-64::absl-py==0.6.1=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyterlab_launcher==0.11.2=py27h28b3542_0  
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pyflakes==1.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::unicodecsv==0.14.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sqlalchemy==1.0.12=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::xlwt==1.0.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::spyder==2.3.8=py27_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::clyent==1.2.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::contextlib2==0.5.4=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::flask-cors==2.1.2=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tensorboard==1.12.0=py27hf484d3e_0
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64::pycurl==7.19.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gcc_linux-64==7.3.0=h553295d_3
  - defaults/linux-64::libxml2==2.9.9=hea5a465_1
  - defaults/linux-64::networkx==2.2=py27_1
  - defaults/linux-64::cytoolz==0.9.0=py27h14c3975_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ipython-notebook==4.0.4=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::bcolz==1.0.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::distributed==1.23.1=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sortedcontainers==2.0.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::mistune==0.7.2=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::chest==0.2.3=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::beautifulsoup4==4.4.1=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::future==0.16.0=py27_2
  - <unknown>/linux-64::docutils==0.12=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::nose==1.3.7=py27_2
  - defaults/linux-64::numpy==1.14.2=py27hdbf6ddf_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::lz4-c==1.8.3=he1b5a44_1001
  - <unknown>/linux-64::runipy==0.1.3=py27_0
  - <unknown>/linux-64::itsdangerous==0.24=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::futures==3.2.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::toolz==0.9.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::gevent==1.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::jinja2==2.8=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libgcc-ng==8.2.0=hdf63c60_1
  - <unknown>/linux-64::ssl_match_hostname==3.4.0.2=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pytz==2016.2=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::jupyter_contrib_core==0.3.3=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::asn1crypto==0.24.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::keras-preprocessing==1.0.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::scikit-learn==0.18.1=np111py27_nomkl_1
 https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::alabaster==0.7.7=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pysocks==1.6.8=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::subprocess32==3.2.7=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::audioread==2.1.4=py27_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ptyprocess==0.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ipython_genutils==0.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::mpmath==0.19=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::traitlets==4.2.1=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::nltk==3.2.4=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::python==2.7.15=h9bab390_4
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::datashape==0.5.1=py27_0
  - anaconda/linux-64::joblib==0.13.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::scipy==1.1.0=py27h7c811a0_2
  - defaults/linux-64::partd==0.3.8=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ipaddress==1.0.14=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::blaze==0.9.1=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::scikit-image==0.12.3=np111py27_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::greenlet==0.4.9=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::ncurses==6.1=hf484d3e_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::qt==4.8.7=1
  - defaults/linux-64::werkzeug==0.14.1=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::gast==0.2.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ruamel_yaml==0.11.14=py27_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ply==3.8=py27_0  
  - defaults/linux-64::plotly==3.4.2=py27h28b3542_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::abstract-rendering==0.5.1=np111py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pyasn1==0.1.9=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::markdown==2.6.9=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::mako==1.0.6=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::html5lib==0.9999999=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::openpyxl==2.3.2=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::statsmodels==0.8.0=np111py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::six==1.10.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::lxml==3.6.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sympy==1.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::c-ares==1.15.0=h7b6447c_1
  - <unknown>/linux-64::py2cairo==1.10.0=py27_2
  - defaults/linux-64::decorator==4.3.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::multipledispatch==0.4.8=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::s3transfer==0.1.13=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pympler==0.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pycparser==2.14=py27_0
  - <unknown>/linux-64::markupsafe==0.23=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::flask==0.12.2=py27h6d5c1cd_0
  - <unknown>/linux-64::rope==0.9.4=py27_1
  - conda-forge/linux-64::jupyter_nbextensions_configurator==0.2.7=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::conda-build==3.2.2=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::spyder-app==2.3.8=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::pytables==3.3.0=np111py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::argcomplete==1.0.0=py27_1
  - conda-forge/linux-64::xz==5.2.4=h14c3975_1001
  - defaults/linux-64::pycosat==0.6.3=py27ha4109ae_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::snowballstemmer==1.2.1=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::sqlite==3.25.3=h7b6447c_0
  - defaults/linux-64::unittest2==1.1.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zict==0.1.3=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::backports==1.0=py27h63c9359_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::ipython==4.1.2=py27_1
  - conda-forge/linux-64::resampy==0.1.5=np111py27_1
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py27_7
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::jupyter_core==4.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sockjs-tornado==1.0.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::singledispatch==3.4.0.3=py27_0
- conda-forge/linux-64::resampy==0.1.5=np111py27_1
  - defaults/linux-64::jupyter==1.0.0=py27_7
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::jupyter_core==4.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sockjs-tornado==1.0.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::singledispatch==3.4.0.3=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::openssl==1.1.1b=h14c3975_1
  - https://conda.binstar.org/auto/linux-64::libpgm==1.2=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::backports.weakref==1.0rc1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::filelock==2.0.7=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::conda-manager==0.3.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::numexpr==2.6.2=np111py27_nomkl_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::zeromq==4.2.5=hfc679d8_4
  - defaults/linux-64::libffi==3.2.1=hd88cf55_4
  - defaults/linux-64::hdf5==1.10.2=hba1933b_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::py4j==0.10.6=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::fontconfig==2.11.1=5
  - conda-forge/linux-64::patsy==0.4.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::psutil==4.1.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sphinx==1.3.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::babel==2.2.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pygpu==0.7.6=py27h035aef0_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::python-libarchive-c==2.8=py27_1004
  - defaults/linux-64::libssh2==1.8.0=h1ba5d50_4
  - <unknown>/linux-64::beautiful-soup==4.3.2=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::tensorflow-base==1.12.0=mkl_py27h3c3e929_0  
  - defaults/linux-64::click==6.7=py27h4225b90_0
  - defaults/linux-64::linecache2==1.0.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::locket==0.2.0=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::conda==4.7.5=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::qtawesome==0.3.2=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cloudpickle==0.5.5=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::cython==0.28.5=py27hf484d3e_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::terminado==0.5=py27_1
  - defaults/linux-64::cryptography==2.4.1=py27h1ba5d50_0
  - defaults/linux-64::pyyaml==3.12=py27h2d70dd7_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::heapdict==1.0.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::grpcio==1.16.1=py27hf8bcb03_1
  - defaults/linux-64::traceback2==1.4.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::astor==0.7.1=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pyqt==4.11.4=py27_1
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::wheel==0.29.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::dill==0.2.4=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::mkl-service==1.1.2=py27he904b0f_5
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::py==1.4.31=py27_0
  - <unknown>/linux-64::redis-py==2.10.3=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::anaconda-navigator==1.1.0=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::zlib==1.2.11=ha838bed_2
  - defaults/linux-64::tblib==1.3.2=py27h51fe5ba_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::simplegeneric==0.8.1=py27_0
  - conda-forge/linux-64::libsodium==1.0.16=h470a237_1
  - defaults/linux-64::s3fs==0.1.6=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::sip==4.16.9=py27_0
  - defaults/linux-64::libprotobuf==3.6.1=hd408876_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::pyspark==2.2.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::bleach==1.5.0=py27_0
  - https://repo.continuum.io/pkgs/free/linux-64::python-dateutil==2.5.1=py27_0
...
```

Update:

```
1. On Ubuntu 16.06, I tried exporting the ‘base’ and ‘ai’ environments to .yml files, deleted ~/anaconda, reinstalled Anaconda and tried to restore my ‘ai’ environment.
condo complained about hundred of conflicts.

-rwxr-xr-x    1 ubuntu ubuntu 499266771 Sep 11 16:57 Anaconda2-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh

$ conda env create -f ai_environment.yml 
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
Warning: you have pip-installed dependencies in your environment file, but you do not list pip itself as one of your conda dependencies.  Conda may not use the correct pip to install your packages, and they may end up in the wrong place.  Please add an explicit pip dependency.  I'm adding one for you, but still nagging you.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
done
Solving environment: - 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining backports.shutil_get_terminal_size:  21%|▏| 65/316 [00:00<00:00, 4464.Examining pyserial:  21%|████▏               | 66/316 [00:00<00:00, 4488.21it/s]Examining jupyter_nbextensions_configurator:  66%|▋| 210/316 [00:00<00:00, 4888.Examining packaging:  67%|████████████      | 211/316 [00:00<00:00, 4900.24it/s]Examining sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml:  88%|▉| 277/316 [00:00<00:00, 4816.54itExamining astor:  88%|███████████████████▎  | 278/316 [00:00<00:00, 4820.70itfailed                                                                             

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package pyzmq conflicts for:
jupyter_client==5.2.3=py36_0 -> pyzmq[version='>=13']
notebook==5.7.8=py36_0 -> pyzmq[version='>=17']
Package mkl conflicts for:
mkl_fft==1.0.10=py36_0 -> mkl
pytorch==0.4.0=py36hdf912b8_0 -> mkl[version='>=2018.0.2,<2019.0a0']
mkl_random==1.0.2=py36_0 -> mkl
Package ujson conflicts for:
spacy==2.0.12=py36h962f231_0 -> ujson[version='>=1.35']
Package jinja2 conflicts for:
notebook==5.7.8=py36_0 -> jinja2
nbconvert==5.5.0=py_0 -> jinja2
Package h5py conflicts for:
keras-base==2.2.4=py36_0 -> h5py
Package libsodium conflicts for:
pyzmq==17.0.0=py36h14c3975_0 -> libsodium
zeromq==4.2.5=h439df22_0 -> libsodium[version='>=1.0.16,<1.0.17.0a0']
Package keras-preprocessing conflicts for:
keras-base==2.2.4=py36_0 -> keras-preprocessing[version='>=1.0.5']
tensorflow==1.13.1=py36_0 -> keras-preprocessing[version='>=1.0.5']
Package murmurhash conflicts for:
spacy==2.0.12=py36h962f231_0 -> murmurhash[version='>=0.28,<0.29']
Package libgfortran-ng conflicts for:
hdf5==1.10.2=hba1933b_1 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
libopenblas==0.3.3=h5a2b251_3 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
blas==2.7=openblas -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
numpy-base==1.16.2=py36h2f8d375_0 -> libgfortran-ng[version='>=7,<8.0a0']
Package protobuf conflicts for:
chainer==4.2.0=py36_0 -> protobuf[version='>=3.0.0']
tensorflow==1.13.1=py36_0 -> protobuf[version='>=3.6.1']
tensorflow-tensorboard==1.5.1=py36hf484d3e_1 -> protobuf
tensorboard==1.13.1=py36_0 -> protobuf[version='>=3.4.0']
Package tk conflicts for:
python==3.6.7=h0371630_0 -> tk[version='>=8.6.8,<8.7.0a0']
Package blas conflicts for:
libcblas==3.8.0=7_openblas -> blas=[build=openblas]
scikit-learn==0.20.3=py36h22eb022_0 -> blas=[build=openblas]
libblas==3.8.0=7_openblas -> blas=[build=openblas]
liblapacke==3.8.0=7_openblas -> blas=[build=openblas]
numpy-base==1.16.2=py36h2f8d375_0 -> blas=[build=openblas]
nomkl==3.0=0 -> blas=[build=openblas]
liblapack==3.8.0=7_openblas -> blas=[build=openblas]
Package keras-applications conflicts for:
keras-base==2.2.4=py36_0 -> keras-applications[version='>=1.0.6']
tensorflow==1.13.1=py36_0 -> keras-applications[version='>=1.0.6']
Package ninja conflicts for:
pytorch==0.4.0=py36hdf912b8_0 -> ninja
Package requests conflicts for:
spacy==2.0.12=py36h962f231_0 -> requests[version='>=2.13.0,<3.0.0']
Package dbus conflicts for:
qt==5.9.7=h5867ecd_1 -> dbus[version='>=1.13.2,<2.0a0']
pyqt==5.9.2=py36h751905a_0 -> dbus[version='>=1.12.2,<2.0a0']
Package pandocfilters conflicts for:
nbconvert==5.5.0=py_0 -> pandocfilters[version='>=1.4.1']
Package liblapacke conflicts for:
libblas==3.8.0=7_openblas -> liblapacke==3.8.0=7_openblas
libcblas==3.8.0=7_openblas -> liblapacke==3.8.0=7_openblas
liblapack==3.8.0=7_openblas -> liblapacke==3.8.0=7_openblas
blas==2.7=openblas -> liblapacke==3.8.0=7_openblas
Package ptyprocess conflicts for:
pexpect==4.6.0=py36_0 -> ptyprocess[version='>=0.5']
terminado==0.8.1=py36_1 -> ptyprocess
Package nbformat conflicts for:
nbconvert==5.5.0=py_0 -> nbformat[version='>=4.4']
notebook==5.7.8=py36_0 -> nbformat
Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
libgcc-ng==8.2.0=hdf63c60_1 -> _libgcc_mutex=[build=main]
Package cudnn conflicts for:
pytorch==0.4.0=py36hdf912b8_0 -> cudnn[version='>=7.1.2,<=8.0a0']
Package zeromq conflicts for:
pyzmq==17.0.0=py36h14c3975_0 -> zeromq[version='>=4.2.3,<4.3']
Package pygments conflicts for:
prompt_toolkit==2.0.9=py_0 -> pygments
ipython==7.5.0=py36h24bf2e0_0 -> pygments
nbconvert==5.5.0=py_0 -> pygments
Package plac conflicts for:
spacy==2.0.12=py36h962f231_0 -> plac[version='>=0.9.6,<1.0.0']
Package pango conflicts for:
graphviz==2.40.1=h21bd128_2 -> pango[version='>=1.42.1,<2.0a0']
Package python conflicts for:
tornado==5.0.2=py36_0 -> python[version='3.6.*|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
pycparser==2.18=py36hf9f622e_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
jupyter_core==4.4.0=py36h7c827e3_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
murmurhash==0.28.0=py36_0 -> python=3.6
python-dateutil==2.7.3=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
filelock==3.0.4=py36_0 -> python[version='3.6.*|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
multicore-tsne==0.1_d4ff4aab=py36h3e44d54_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
pexpect==4.6.0=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
idna==2.7=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
tblib==1.3.2=py36h34cf8b6_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
astor==0.6.2=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
jupyterlab==0.32.1=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
scikit-learn==0.20.3=py36h22eb022_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
numpy-base==1.16.2=py36h2f8d375_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
jupyterlab_launcher==0.10.5=py36_0 -> python[version='3.6.*|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
kiwisolver==1.0.1=py36h764f252_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
ujson==1.35=py36_0 -> python=3.6
cycler==0.10.0=py36h93f1223_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
boto==2.48.0=py36h6e4cd66_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
ipykernel==5.1.1=py36h24bf2e0_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
six==1.12.0=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
requests==2.22.0=py36_1 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
pyemd==0.5.1=py36ha8d69ae_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
tensorflow-probability==0.5.0=py_1 -> python
chainer==4.2.0=py36_0 -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0']
docutils==0.14=py36hb0f60f5_0 -> python[version=
…

2. I tried exporting my ‘ai’ environment from my Mac and importing it on Ubuntu 16.06. I
failed because of missing packages. Are these packages that I built from source that conda can’t find?


(base) ubuntu@ip-10-0-1-71:~$ conda env create -f ai_mac_environment.yml 
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): | NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound: 
  - pymongo==3.7.2=py36h0a44026_0
  - pygpu==0.7.6=py36h917ab60_1000
  - gensim==3.4.0=py36h1de35cc_0
  - pytorch==1.1.0=py3.6_0
  - ninja==1.9.0=h04f5b5a_0
  - matplotlib==2.2.2=py36ha7267d0_0
  - graphviz==2.38.0=hbeef861_8
  - openssl==1.1.1=h1de35cc_0
  - scikit-learn==0.20.3=py36hebd9d1a_0
  - libgpuarray==0.7.6=h1de35cc_1003
  - kiwisolver==1.1.0=py36h770b8ee_0
  - tornado==6.0.2=py36h01d97ff_0
  - python==3.6.7=haf84260_0
  - libopenblas==0.3.3=hdc02c5d_3
  - tensorboard==1.12.2=py36haf313ee_0
  - msgpack-python==0.6.1=py36h04f5b5a_0
  - grpcio==1.12.1=py36hd9629dc_0
  - webencodings==0.5.1=py36_0
  - tensorflow-base==1.12.0=mkl_py36h70e0e9a_0
  - pandoc==2.2.1=hde52d81_0
  - appnope==0.1.0=py36_0
  - boto==2.48.0=py36hdbc59ac_1
  - libprotobuf==3.6.1=hd9629dc_1000
  - protobuf==3.6.1=py36h0a44026_1001
  - xz==5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - python-crfsuite==0.9.6=py36h04f5b5a_1000
  - readline==7.0=hc1231fa_4
  - thinc==6.10.1=py36h17d75cb_0
  - libgfortran==3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - scipy==1.2.1=py36hbd7caa9_1
  - cymem==1.31.2=py36hfc679d8_0
  - numpy-base==1.16.2=py36ha711998_0
  - openblas==0.3.5=h436c29b_1001
  - numpy==1.16.2=py36hbb3c62a_1
  - cryptography==2.3.1=py36ha12b0ac_2
  - tensorflow==1.12.0=mkl_py36h2b2bbaf_0

3. I tried reverting conda to rev 0 after reinstalling Anaconda2-2019.07-Linux-x86_64.sh

4. I tried to install my previous environment with 
$ conda env create -f ai_environment.yml 
This got hundreds of conflicts

5. I tried to install my mac environment with:
$ conda env create -f ai_mac_environment_1.yml 
this got ResolvePackageNotFound: with 38 missing packages.

6. I deleted the missing packages from ai_mac_environment_1.yml and tried again.
NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): \ NVIDIA: no NVIDIA devices found
done
Solving environment: failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:



Package libpng conflicts for:
pillow==5.2.0=py36h2dc6135_1 -> freetype[version='>=2.8,<2.9.0a0'] -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
freetype==2.8.1=0 -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
bokeh==1.0.1=py36_1000 -> pillow[version='>=4.0'] -> freetype[version='2.7|2.7.*,>=2.8,<2.9.0a0,>=2.9.1,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
libpng==1.6.34=ha92aebf_1
seaborn==0.9.0=py_0 -> matplotlib[version='>=1.4.3'] -> pyqt[version='4.*,5.*,5.6.*,5.9.*,>=5.9.2,<5.10.0a0'] -> qt[version='4.8.*,5.6.*,>=4.8.6,<5.0,>=5.6.2,<5.7.0a0'] -> gtk2 -> pango[version='1.40.*,>=1.40.14,<1.41.0a0,>=1.42.4,<1.43.0a0'] -> harfbuzz[version='0.9.*,>=1.7.6,<1.8.0a0,>=1.7.6,<2.0a0,>=1.9.0,<2.0a0,>=2.4.0,<3.0a0'] -> cairo[version='1.14.*,>=1.14.12,<1.15.0a0,>=1.14.12,<2.0a0,>=1.16.0,<1.17.0a0'] -> fontconfig[version='2.11.1,2.12.*,>=2.12.4,<3.0a0,>=2.13.1,<3.0a0'] -> freetype[version='2.5.*,2.6.*,2.8.1,>=2.8,<2.9.0a0,>=2.8.1,<2.9.0a0,>=2.9.1,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
torchvision==0.2.1=py_2 -> pillow[version='>=4.1.1'] -> freetype[version='2.7|2.7.*,>=2.8,<2.9.0a0,>=2.9.1,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
pydot==1.3.0=py36_1000 -> graphviz -> pango[version='>=1.41.0,<2.0a0,>=1.42.1,<2.0a0,>=1.42.4,<1.43.0a0'] -> harfbuzz[version='0.9.*,>=1.7.6,<1.8.0a0,>=1.7.6,<2.0a0,>=1.9.0,<2.0a0,>=2.4.0,<3.0a0'] -> cairo[version='1.14.*,>=1.14.12,<1.15.0a0,>=1.14.12,<2.0a0,>=1.16.0,<1.17.0a0'] -> fontconfig[version='2.11.1,2.12.*,>=2.12.4,<3.0a0,>=2.13.1,<3.0a0'] -> freetype[version='2.5.*,2.6.*,2.8.1,>=2.8,<2.9.0a0,>=2.8.1,<2.9.0a0,>=2.9.1,<3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='1.6.*,>=1.6.23,<1.7,>=1.6.27,<1.7,>=1.6.32,<1.6.35,>=1.6.34,<1.7.0a0']
```

Comment: if the issue is that you are trying to install pytorch try adding the conda forge channel e.g. `conda install -y pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch -c conda-forge`

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately, the conflicts in my Anaconda 'ai' environment andd my base environment
could not be resolved. I had to delete ~/anaconda, re-install it from scratch and reinstall all the packages manually.

Comment: Thanks for this "workaround", hopefully Anaconda team will solve it soon: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8823

Comment: sorry I am confused, why did re-installing anacoda help? Do you mind adding more details on what you did?

Comment: @NoamManos I have hoped for it for years. conda is just bad